# Is there a way to run python scripts without installing anything?

Tags: python

Since installing anything is forbidden and python is unavailable on the School PC, I have only access to Notepad++[[[I know there is a way, but it requires installing something, which i cannot do]]] and visual basic,
can I use any of those to run python scripts?

Comment: No. Running python requires a python interpreter.

Comment: Have someone else install it for you.

Comment: it is very possible to install on school computers if that is what you are wondering, you just don't have access to any folder other than your users. to install just don't check the "install for all users" button and you are good to go

Comment: Running python scripts definitely requires an interpreter. If you are not allowed to install, there are online python interpreters which you can use. You can type and run your code there. This is good for practice only. For actual projects you have to have python in your system.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: I mean technically you can make that interpreter yourself using c, which I am somewhat sure doesn't require any installation? just compile a c python interpreter and you're good to go

Answer (score 5):

No, you need a python interpreter. And with this you can run scripts over the console.
But you can also use an online interpreter https://www.online-python.com/

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to download Python interpreter to be able to run python scripts.

Edit: Or [replit.com](https://replit.com)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You would have to install a Python runtime environment. If you're running macOS you will have Python by default but that is not the case if you're on Windows

Answer (score 0):

use online code compiler or its not possible without installing python

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: programiz.com also gives compiler for other like java, javascript, c, c++ ,c#